# How to to break a braced equation in the middle

Tags: math-mode, equations, alignment

I'm thinking about how to break the following equation:
[image]
As you can see, there is a big brace wrapping up one of the factors in the product integrand. Now I'm trying to change it into the layout in the **edited picture** below:
[image]

My problem is, I don't know how to properly break the factor with **both** braces kept in the **same size**. Here is my original code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8,mathpazo,upgreek,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,mathabx,physics}
\usepackage{enumerate,nicefrac,relsize}
\usepackage{cases,csquotes}

\newcommand{\lrBra}[1]{\left\lbrace#1\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}
Suppose $\lrBra{E_t}_{t>0}$ weakly solves \eqref{Eq: IMCF} with $E_0$ as the initial condition. If $E_0$ is a minimizing hull, then for $0\leq r<s$,
\begin{align}
&m(\Sigma_s)-m(\Sigma_r)\geq\frac{1}{(16\pi)^{\nicefrac{3} 
{2}}}\int_r^s|\Sigma_t|^{\nicefrac{1}{2}}\cdot\label{Eq: weak Gmf}\\
&\lrBra{16\pi-8\pi\chi(\Sigma_t)+\int_{\Sigma_t}\lrbra{2H^{-2}\norm{\mathrm{grad}\ 
H}^2+\mathsf{R}_M+(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2}\dd\mu_{\Sigma_t}}\dd t,\notag
\end{align}
provided that $E_s$ is precompact.
```

I'd like someone to help me achieve the desired layout in the **edited picture**. Thanks for kindly help.

Comment: You're using `amsart`, so you have the full power of `amsmath`.  The break you've chosen is good -- whenever possible, a break preceding a plus or minus is clearest.  I'd use `multline` instead of `align`, and sizing the braces yourself is best.  `\Bigl\{` and `\Bigr\}` are probably good, but maybe `bigg` if they look better a size larger; look at the results and use your best judgment.

Comment: Your code is not complete. There are many undefined control sequences such as `\norm`, `\lrbra`, etc. Do not copy the code into this site until you have compiled it successfully on your local machine.

Comment: And remove unnecessary packages such as `geometry` since they have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. Both `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}` work for me.